# Add HTML Snippet only on specific pages

Tags: html

I would like to add a HTML Snippet on specific pages (not global). This is the snippet:

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dio="http://docs.dionera.com/namespace/DioML">`

Can someone give me a hint, how to solve that? At the moment I use a plugin (insert headers & footers)...but the plugin loads the snippet on each page and not on specific pages.

Thank you very much!

P.S. I don't have much experience in cases like that - sorry.

Comment: you can use the template based condition and add the code. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the wp_head hook like this and checking if it's a post or page you want it to load on with an if statement:

```
function wse_add_snippet_to_header() {
   //replace the array with your own post ids that you want this on
   //replace is_single with is_page if you want to check for pages instead of posts
   if (is_single(array(1234, 1254) {
      ?>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dio="http://docs.dionera.com/namespace/DioML">
      <?php
   }

}
add_action('wp_head', 'wse_add_snippet_to_header');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to add the `xmlns:dio` attribute to the existing HTML tag, not emit a complete second HTML tag.

You could do this by abusing the language_attributes filter, which most themes call in their <html> tag:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> <?php twentytwentyone_the_html_classes(); ?>>
```

e.g.

```php
function language_attributes_xmlns_dio( $output, $doctype ) {
    if ( is_single( array( 1234 ) ) ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:dio="http://docs.dionera.com/namespace/DioML"';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_action( 'language_attributes', 'language_attributes_xmlns_dio', 10, 2 );
```

Although it's possible that some translation plugins overwrite this value completely, so you might lose the namespace in that case. If that's a problem you'd need to edit your theme's header.php to add a new function call inside the <html> tag that you can define in your theme instead to conditionally emit the xmlns attribute. Or there's no harm in an extra namespace, so you could just add it to the tag in header.php unconditionally.

Also it would probably also be better to add a 'needs_dio_namespace' post_meta value to the pages instead and check for that rather than hard-coding IDs.

Comment: I agree with Rup, Catherine's solution is good, but Rup's is more elegant and complies better with coding standards, especially when combine with a meta value to avoid remembering to update a hand-coded list of post/page IDs. Bravo!

Comment: Thank you very much Rup!

Another short question: 

So I have to add your example code to the functions.php? Sure I have to replace the post/page ids, but whats about the "10" or the "2" on the add_action line?

Thank you and sorry for those simple questions...

Comment: This needs to go wherever you're putting custom code, so either in a simple plugin or in your child theme functions.php if you have one. (If you're using a theme that can potentially get updated you want to be careful editing it directly else it might update and lose all your changes.)

Comment: The 10 = filter priority and 2 = number of arguments the filter handler takes, so should be fine as-is and don't need changing.